# simple client/server socket application SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client

so i'm doing a simple client server program using sockets.
mostly i took the code from [KnockKnockServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) but i implemented the client using Threads (this is necessary for me because i want to use it in an android app later)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelpMeServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Database db=new Database();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(50000);
        System.out.println("Listening on port 911");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 911.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("incomig");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("getting printwriter and bufferedreader");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine, outputLine;


    Protocol kkp = new Protocol(db);
    // initiate conversation with client
    System.out.println("listening..");
//Here the exception is thrown.
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
         kkp.processInput(inputLine);
         //if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
            //break;
    }        out.close();
    in.close();
    clientSocket.close();
    serverSocket.close();
}
}
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Protocol {
private static final int WAITING = 0;
private static final int REGISTERING = 1;
private static final int LOGIN = 2;

private int state = WAITING;
private Database db;
private String email;
private String password;
public Protocol(Database db)
{
    this.db=db;
    email=null;
    password=null;
}
public void processInput(String theInput) {
    System.out.println("Cliet: "+theInput);


    if (state == WAITING) {
        if(theInput.equals("register"))
            {
            state=REGISTERING;
            System.out.println("set state to registering");
            }
        else if(theInput=="login"){
            state=LOGIN;
            System.out.println("set state to registering");
        }
        }


    else if(state == REGISTERING)
    {
        if(email==null) {
            email=theInput;
            System.out.println("set email to "+email);
        }
        else {
            password=theInput;
            System.out.println("saving "+email);
            db.addUser(new String(email), new String(password));
            password=null;
            email=null;
            state=WAITING;
        }
    }
}
}
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;

public class NetworkingThread extends Thread{

Socket kkSocket;
PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;
public void run()
    {
    kkSocket = null;
    out = null;
    in = null;

    try {
        kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 50000);
        out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: taranis.");
        System.exit(1);
    }   

}
public void close()
{
    out.close();
    try {
        in.close();
        kkSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void write(String s)
{
    out.println(s);  
    out.flush();
}
}

public class go {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
        NetworkingThread n=new NetworkingThread();
    n.start();
    n.write("register");
    n.write("a@gmail.com");
    n.write("password");
    n.close();

}

 }
```

my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at HelpMeServer.main(HelpMeServer.java:34)
```

if i take this code and put in the run method of NetworkThread my error goes away. But i can't use this in my app, i have to call these methods from outside

```
n.write("register");
n.write("a@gmail.com");
n.write("password");
n.close();
```

so the changes i made according to your advice(still the same error at the same place)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelpMeServer {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Database db=new Database();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(50000);
        System.out.println("Listening on port 911");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 911.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

   while(true)
   {
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("incomig");
        ClientThread t=new ClientThread(clientSocket,db);
        t.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
   }
  }
          }

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ClientThread extends Thread {

Socket clientSocket;
Database db;
public ClientThread(Socket s,Database db)
{
    clientSocket=s;
    this.db=db;
}
public void run()
{
     System.out.println("getting printwriter and bufferedreader");
        PrintWriter out;
        try {
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine, outputLine;


                Protocol kkp = new Protocol(db);
                System.out.println("listening..");
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {//error!
                     kkp.processInput(inputLine);
                     //if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                        //break;
                } 
                out.close();
               in.close();
               clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this work you have to put the `serverSocket.accept()` in a loop. At the moment you get one message and then close the server socket, so any subsequent tries to connect to your server will be denied because there is no server socket listening.

Comment: how exactly should the loop look?

Comment: You say you have read the java tutorial on socket programming. At the end of the page is a paragraph headed "Supporting multiple clients" which explains how it works.

Comment: well i  changed it according to the paragraph but i still get the same error.

Comment: i edited the code above so you can see how my code looks now

Comment: Do you get any more output from the program?

Comment: this is all the output i get:
Listening on port 911
incomig
getting printwriter and bufferedreader
listening..
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:30)

Comment: OK, then have you tried to debug your program? I think that all strings are concatenated together and therefore you cannot distinguish between the words in the server. Please try to solve this problem first and if you have still problems after this come back here to SO. BTW try to learn something about protocol design.

Comment: that is definitely not the problem. as i said in the beginning when i move these calls n.write("register");
    n.write("a@gmail.com");
    n.write("password");
    n.close(); from the main method into the run method of NetworkThread there is no exception

Comment: When there is nothing put on the console you have a problem with your protocol.

Comment: this is on console when i put the calls to write inside the run method of Network thread:
Listening on port 911
incomig
getting printwriter and bufferedreader
listening..
Cliet: register
set state to registering
Cliet: a@gmail.com
set email to a@gmail.com
Cliet: password
saving a@gmail.com
adding a@gmail.com
and this if i put it outside (call it from the main method):
incomig
getting printwriter and bufferedreader
listening..
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset...

Comment: if that is problem with the protocol please be more thorough where do you think the problem is..

Comment: You added some code as `System.out.println("set state to registering")` to your code. This must be placed on the console (in either case). If the output is not there then your protocol is not working.

Comment: it is on my output.just check in my previous comment